# antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I need to be able to insert the score into the database. I have a command to update an existing score but I don't find how to enter a new one.

it is my first time that use JPA to connect a spring boot app with a database(MySQL) but I am making it for a school project.

JpaScoreDao class

```
package service;

@Repository("scoreDao")
public class JpaScoreDao implements ScoreDao{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Score> alleScoreFilm(Long filmId) {
        TypedQuery<Score> query = em.createNamedQuery("Score.alleScoreFilm", Score.class)
                                    .setParameter("filmId", filmId);
        return query.getResultList();       
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public int updateScore(int rating, Long id) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Score.updateScore")
                        .setParameter("rating", rating)
                        .setParameter("id", id);
        return query.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insert(Score score) {
        em.persist(score);      
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void nieuweScore(Long filmId, String user, int rating) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Score.nieuweScore")
                        .setParameter("rating", rating)
                        .setParameter("user", user)
                        .setParameter("filmId", filmId);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Film

```
package domain;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Film.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM Film f ORDER BY f.naam"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Film.findFilmByName", query = "SELECT f FROM Film f WHERE f.naam like :filmNaam"),

})
public class Film implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String naam;
    
    private String[] regisseurs;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "score_user")
    private List<Score> ratings;
    
    private int totaleRating;
    
    private String code;
    
    public Film(String naam, String[] regisseurs, Map<String, Integer> ratings, String code) {
        this.naam = naam;
        this.regisseurs = regisseurs;
        if (ratings != null) {
            this.ratings = ratings.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(e -> new Score(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), null))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else {
            this.ratings = new ArrayList<Score>();
        }
        this.setTotaleRating();
        this.code = code;
    }
    
    protected Film() {
        
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(naam);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Film other = (Film) obj;
        return Objects.equals(naam, other.naam);
    }

    public String getNaam() {
        return naam;
    }

    public void setName(String naam) {
        this.naam = naam;
    }
    
    public Map<String, Integer> getRatings() {
        Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Score s: ratings) {
            m.put(s.getUser(), s.getRating());
        }
        return m;
    }
    
    public String[] getRegisseurs() {
        return regisseurs;
    }
    
    public void addRatings(String user, int rating, Long id) {
        this.ratings.add(new Score(user, rating, id));
    }
    
    public Integer returnTotaleRating() {
        int sum = 0;
        if (ratings != null) {
            if (!ratings.isEmpty()) {
                for (Score s: ratings) {
                    sum += s.getRating();
                }
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public void setRegisseurs(String[] regisseurs) {
        this.regisseurs = regisseurs;       
    }
    
    
    public Integer getTotaleRating() {
        return returnTotaleRating();
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setTotaleRating() {
        int totaal = 0;
        for (Score s: ratings) {
            totaal += s.getRating();
        }
        this.totaleRating = totaal;
    }   
}
```

Console with error

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: values
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1163) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:825) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.insertStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:373) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:346) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at 
2022-08-18 13:14:16.241 ERROR 3044 --- [           main] o.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl  : HHH000177: Error in named query: Score.nieuweScore

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: values near line 1, column 52 [INSERT INTO Score ('rating', 'user', 'score_user') values :rating, :user, :filmId]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:346) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at com.springBoot.Filmfestival_JPA.SpringBootFilmfestivalJpaApplication.main(SpringBootFilmfestivalJpaApplication.java:22) ~[classes/:na]

2022-08-18 13:14:16.242 ERROR 3044 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
Score.nieuweScore failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: values near line 1, column 52 [INSERT INTO Score ('rating', 'user', 'score_user') values :rating, :user, :filmId]
2022-08-18 13:14:16.243  WARN 3044 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/springBoot/Filmfestival_JPA/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
Score.nieuweScore failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: values near line 1, column 52 [INSERT INTO Score ('rating', 'user', 'score_user') values :rating, :user, :filmId]
2022-08-18 13:14:16.244  INFO 3044 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-18 13:14:16.252  INFO 3044 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-18 13:14:16.264 ERROR 3044 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/springBoot/Filmfestival_JPA/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
Score.nieuweScore failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: values near line 1, column 52 [INSERT INTO Score ('rating', 'user', 'score_user') values :rating, :user, :filmId]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at com.springBoot.Filmfestival_JPA.SpringBootFilmfestivalJpaApplication.main(SpringBootFilmfestivalJpaApplication.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
Score.nieuweScore failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: values near line 1, column 52 [INSERT INTO Score ('rating', 'user', 'score_user') values :rating, :user, :filmId]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
Score.nieuweScore failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: values near line 1, column 52 [INSERT INTO Score ('rating', 'user', 'score_user') values :rating, :user, :filmId]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:360) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

The error essentially says that the query `INSERT INTO Score ('rating', 'user', 'score_user') values :rating, :user, :filmId` is invalid. First of all, you have to understand that there are two query languages at play here. SQL is the underlying query language of your database and then there is HQL which is the query language Hibernate understands. HQL is translated to SQL, but it is an abstraction that tries to hide most of the SQL dialect specifics.

Now, the query you wrote there is neither valid SQL nor HQL. The valid SQL version of this would look like `INSERT INTO Score (rating, user, score_user) values (:rating, :user, :filmId)`. In HQL, you can't represent this. So if you must use a named query, you will have to use a "named native query".

Hibernate is an ORM though, which means that it can synchronize objects with the database. You don't have to write HQL or SQL queries to do simple things like insert/update/delete. You usually just instantiate an object, and then give that to Hibernate to synchronize it with the database.

In your particular case, remove the named query `Score.nieuweScore` and instead use this code:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void nieuweScore(Long filmId, String user, int rating) {
    Film f = em.find(Film.class, filmId);
    f.addRatings(user, rating, null);
}
```